# Extracting appointments from shared Outlook calendar to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract appointments from a shared Outlook calendar to Excel using a VBA macro in Excel. The code fails whether I try to define **objOwner** and **olFolderCalendar** as either **Object** or **Outlook.Recipient** / **Outlook.Folder** for use in the **GetSharedDefaultFolder** method.

I get the **Run-time error '13': Type mismatch** error on the following line:

```
Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub ListAppointments()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim objOwner As Object
Dim olFolderCalendar As Object

Dim NextRow As Long

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("test@test.com")

objOwner.Resolve

If objOwner.Resolved Then

    MsgBox objOwner.Name
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)

End If

Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Location")

NextRow = 2

For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
    Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
    Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
    Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End
    Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
Next olApt

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The cause of your issue was using an object for `olFolderCalendar`, however in context for what you are trying to do you want an `Enumeration` value of olFolderCalendar which has a value of **9**.

I've tidied up the code, and made a few optimization to make this code faster, and added a basic error handler. Great first post :)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListAppointments()
On Error GoTo ErrHand:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'This is an enumeration value in context of getDefaultSharedFolder
    Const olFolderCalendar As Byte = 9

    Dim olApp       As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olNS        As Object: Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olFolder    As Object
    Dim olApt       As Object
    Dim objOwner    As Object: Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("emailAddressHERE")
    Dim NextRow     As Long
    Dim ws          As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then 
        Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
    end if

    ws.Range("A1:D1").Value2 = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Location")

    'Ensure there at least 1 item to continue
    If olFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Create an array large enough to hold all records
    Dim myArr() As Variant: ReDim myArr(0 To 3, 0 To olFolder.Items.Count - 1)

    'Add the records to an array
    'Add this error skip, as I found some of my calendar items don't have all properties e.g. a start time
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        myArr(0, NextRow) = olApt.Subject
        myArr(1, NextRow) = olApt.Start
        myArr(2, NextRow) = olApt.End
        myArr(3, NextRow) = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Write all records to a worksheet from an array, this is much faster
    ws.Range("A2:D" & NextRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArr)

    'AutoFit
    ws.Columns.AutoFit

cleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    'Add error handler
    Resume cleanExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

here's the code @Ryan Wildry wrote for you with a start and end date input, in case you want to export it for a specified period of time. You need to add the following lines:

```
Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date

   FromDate = InputBox("Enter the start date (format: yyyy/mm/dd)")
   ToDate = InputBox("Enter the end date(format: yyyy/mm/dd)")
   For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
    If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
        myArr(0, NextRow) = olApt.Subject
        myArr(1, NextRow) = olApt.Start
        myArr(2, NextRow) = olApt.End
        myArr(3, NextRow) = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change:

`Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)`

with this :

`Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)`