# Getting Recurring Calendar Meeting to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Recurring meeting not showing after running the code above. Is there any solution for this issue?

The orginal code from [Extracting appointments from shared Outlook calendar to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447945/extracting-appointments-from-shared-outlook-calendar-to-excel/)

```
Public Sub ListAppointments()
On Error GoTo ErrHand:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'This is an enumeration value in context of getDefaultSharedFolder
    Const olFolderCalendar As Byte = 9

    Dim olApp       As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olNS        As Object: Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olFolder    As Object
    Dim olApt       As Object
    Dim objOwner    As Object: Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("emailAddressHERE")
    Dim NextRow     As Long
    Dim ws          As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then 
        Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
    end if

    ws.Range("A1:D1").Value2 = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Location")

    'Ensure there at least 1 item to continue
    If olFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Create an array large enough to hold all records
    Dim myArr() As Variant: ReDim myArr(0 To 3, 0 To olFolder.Items.Count - 1)

    'Add the records to an array
    'Add this error skip, as I found some of my calendar items don't have all properties e.g. a start time
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        myArr(0, NextRow) = olApt.Subject
        myArr(1, NextRow) = olApt.Start
        myArr(2, NextRow) = olApt.End
        myArr(3, NextRow) = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Write all records to a worksheet from an array, this is much faster
    ws.Range("A2:D" & NextRow + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArr)

    'AutoFit
    ws.Columns.AutoFit

cleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    'Add error handler
    Resume cleanExit
End Sub
```

the code shows the meetings on the calendar which is awesome, but if there is a recurring meeting it will not show it. I need to include all meetings even recurring.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the [Items.IncludeRecurrences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences) property to true if you want to get recurring appointments.

I have noticed the following code:

```
'Create an array large enough to hold all records
    Dim myArr() As Variant: ReDim myArr(0 To 3, 0 To olFolder.Items.Count - 1)
```

Maintaining all items in the array is not really a good idea in Outlook. What if the folder contains thousands of items?

I'd suggest getting items by chunks, for example, for a month. The Find/FindNext and Restrict items of the Items class do job for you:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am not sure how to add  myAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True 
 to the code above

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the sample code listed in the articles I mentioned in my post.